# mongodb does not shutdown cleanly on system shutdown

Tags: ssh, shutdown, mongodb

When I shutdown Ubuntu running mongodb (installed via apt), occasionally mongodb doesn't appear to finish shutting down completely - the log file matches a healthy shutdown, closing files, cleaning up the journal etc.. but the filnal `[interruptThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...` isn't present, and (unsurprisingly) mongodb refuses to start at the next bootup, complaining of a stale lock file.

It appears to me that there is a timeout for services to quit by themselves that is expiring, and thus mongodb is killed forcibly.

The offending mongodb is part of a replica set that sync's over ssh tunnels. It may thus be possible that a socket is hanging and holding up the final cleanup (including removing the lock file)??

What can I do about this? Can I set a longer timeout for mongodb to shutdown? Can I insist that mongodb be allowed to die cleanly before ssh tunnels are killed? Is there another explanation that I'm missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there is a limit on the time that services are allowed to take to shut down. Ubuntu uses upstart to start and stop services, and upstart's default limit for that is 5 seconds (see the [upstart documentation on kill timeout](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#kill-timeout)). Possibly it will solve your problem if you increase that timeout. You have to place the `kill timeout` directive mentioned in the link in the upstart configuration file for mongodb. On Ubuntu 12.04, this file is found at `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`. You can find an upstart file that contains the `kill timeout` directive in the [current mongodb source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/1b4c5d4f2c1ea6f25a035884adc7fea884c25334/debian/mongod.upstart). (However, this file may not work on your Ubuntu system due to different paths.)

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04 even without replication, and for me `kill timeout 300` fixed the problem.